# ionic 2 : screenOrientation.lock(LANDSCAPE) on ipad rotate app when launched in landscape_secondary

Tags: ipad, ionic2, ionic3, screen-orientation

I have an issue with ScreenOrientation ionic-Native component on ipad.
I lock orientation to landscape like this

```
this.screenOrientation.lock(this.platform.is('tablet') ?
this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE : 
this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT)
        .catch(console.error);
```

On ipad, when I launch my app in landscape primary, it works, but when I launch it in landscape secondary, my app auto-rotate and flip upside-down.

Comment: You can lock screen orientation to landscape in your `config.xml` file.

`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`

Comment: sorry i didn't add the precision, but i need to lock landscape on tablets and portrait on smartphones

Comment: try to get the current orientation type on tablet using `this.screenOrientation.type` and set landscape-primary or landscape-secondary accordingly.

Comment: For iOS devices you can do it from Xcode. In Xcode under deployment info adjust the orientation the way you want for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: You could create two builds, one for phones and one for tablets.